# I'm trying to add animation to my web page title using anime.js and jQuery, but it throws an error

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, reactjs, anime.js

I have an **About us** web page and I need to animate this title:

[image]

I found [this](https://tobiasahlin.com/moving-letters/#12) one, that uses `anime.js` and `jQuery`.

Here's my **About.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import '../css/About.css'
import '../scripts/aboutAnimation'
import AboutInfo from "../components/AboutInfo";


const About = () => {
    return (
        <div className="containerAbout">
            <div className="title-container">
                <p className="title">About us...</p>
            </div>
            <div className="forest">
                <AboutInfo
                    name="Vasiliy Pupkin"
                    number="+375 29 973 79 43"
                    email="vasyapupkin@gmail.com"
                    position="top"
                />
                <AboutInfo
                    name="Aleksey Smirnov"
                    number="+375 29 337 91 07"
                    email="asmirn@gmail.com"
                    position="middle"
                />
                <AboutInfo
                    name="Ivan Karpovski"
                    number="+375 29 655 74 25"
                    email="karpovski@gmail.com"
                    position="down"
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default About;
```

Here's my **aboutAnimation.js:**

```
import anime from 'animejs/lib/anime.es.js';


let textWrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('title');
textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/\S/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>");

anime.timeline({loop: true})
    .add({
        targets: '.title .letter',
        translateX: [40,0],
        translateZ: 0,
        opacity: [0,1],
        easing: "easeOutExpo",
        duration: 1200,
        delay: (el, i) => 500 + 30 * i
    }).add({
    targets: '.title .letter',
    translateX: [0,-30],
    opacity: [1,0],
    easing: "easeInExpo",
    duration: 1100,
    delay: (el, i) => 100 + 30 * i
});
```

This is an error I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
```

I've deleted the 5th line and checked if `textWrapper` exists through `console.log()` command, and console shows something like this:

[image]

By the way: if I type those 2 lines in Chrome console, I get this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use,

```
let textWrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('title')[0];
textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/\S/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>");
```

Because getElementsByClassName returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names.

Try assigning some id to p tag and try using getElementById

```
let textWrapper = document.getElementById('title');
textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/\S/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>");
```

Am Adding new Functional Component Solution! I think this might help you.

```
import React from 'react';
import '../css/About.css';
import AboutInfo from "../components/AboutInfo";

// THE PACKAGE I HAVE USED
import anime from 'animejs';

export default function App() {
  const animationRef = React.useRef(null);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    let textWrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('title');
    textWrapper[0].innerHTML = textWrapper[0].textContent.replace(/\S/g, "<span className='letter'>$&</span>");

    animationRef.current =
      anime.timeline({ loop: true })
        .add({
          targets: document.querySelectorAll('.title, .letter'),
          translateX: [40, 0],
          translateZ: 0,
          opacity: [0, 1],
          easing: "easeOutExpo",
          duration: 1200,
          delay: (el, i) => 500 + 30 * i
        }).add({
          targets: document.querySelectorAll('.title, .letter'),
          translateX: [0, -30],
          opacity: [1, 0],
          easing: "easeInExpo",
          duration: 1100,
          delay: (el, i) => 100 + 30 * i
        });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="containerAbout">
        <div className="title-container">
            <p className="title">About us...</p>
        </div>
        <div className="forest">
            <AboutInfo
                name="Vasiliy Pupkin"
                number="+375 29 973 79 43"
                email="vasyapupkin@gmail.com"
                position="top"
            />
            <AboutInfo
                name="Aleksey Smirnov"
                number="+375 29 337 91 07"
                email="asmirn@gmail.com"
                position="middle"
            />
            <AboutInfo
                name="Ivan Karpovski"
                number="+375 29 655 74 25"
                email="karpovski@gmail.com"
                position="down"
            />
        </div>
    </div>
);
}
```

Comment: I've tried to assign an id to my p tag but it throws: ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null```

Comment: The most interesting part is that when I type

```let textWrapper = document.getElementById('title');
textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/\S/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>");``` it executes successfully.

Comment: Nope. As I said I get this: ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null```. It works only in console.

Comment: It may be one of the cause that, the p tag of Abort is not mounted to DOM.

Comment: What does that means and how can I fix it?

Comment: Where will you include the aboutAnimate component?

Comment: it's not a component, it's just .```js``` file. I imported it to my **About.js** file (its code is specified in the top of my question)